# Why connecting to a socket created by createRfcommSocket is faster than createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord?

Tags: android, sockets, reflection, bluetooth

Why is that connecting to a bluetooth socket that was created by createRfcommSocket using reflection is faster than that created by createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord?

```
BluetoothSocket socket = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
socket.connect();
```

vs

```
Class<?> cls = temp.getRemoteDevice().getClass();
Class<?>[] paramTypes = new Class<?>[]{ Integer.TYPE };
Method m = cls.getMethod("createRfcommSocket", paramTypes);
Object[] params = new Object[]{ Integer.valueOf(1) };
fallbackSocket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(temp.getRemoteDevice(), params);
```

The difference is especially noticeable when connecting a device over a long range. Tradition method fails to connect multiple times, let alone the connect call takes noticeably longer time to process. On other the hand, connection to socket created by reflection method is made from the first time, and call to connect() is quick.

Is there a relatively simple explanation it is so?

Answer (score 3):

The relatively simple explanation is that the former method is making a connection to an SDP service record. SDP maps a UUID to a channel, and so the former has to look up the channel to connect to using SDP.

With the latter you are telling it you want to connect directly to channel 1, so no SDP discovery has to be done to figure out which channel the UUID is mapped to. No SDP lookup means less time to do the connection.

Comment: You may probably help us TIA: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69041213/12204620